# If else statement not working in ajax template

Tags: ajax, django

title_posts.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load humanize %}
{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/title_posts.css' %}">
{% endblock styles %}

{% block content %}
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("{{ game.cover_display.url }}");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100% auto;
            background-color: #171717;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: 0 3.5rem;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container black2 container-nav gamenav">
        <ul class="quantico">
            <li><a class="text-light nav-link" href="{% url 'title-posts' game.title %}">Updates</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-light nav-link" href="{% url 'title-bugs' game.title %}">Bugs</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-light nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/{{ game.twitter }}">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-light nav-link" href="https://www.reddit.com/r/{{ game.reddit }}">Reddit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container black container-position">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                <img class="cover-image-height" src="{{ game.cover.url }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <p>{{ game.description| safe }}</p>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" id="platform" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Select Platform
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="plat-form-options">
                        {% for platform in game.platform.all %}
                            <option class="dropdown-item" value="{{ platform.id }}"
                                    onclick="platFormSelect('{% url 'title-posts-ajax' title=game.title platform_id=platform.id %}', '{{ platform }}')">{{ platform }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="posts_data">
        </div>
        {% if is_paginated %}

            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                    <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}
    </div>



    <script>


        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($("#plat-form-options option").length > 0) {
                $("#plat-form-options option")[0].click();
            }

        });


        function platFormSelect(url, platform) {
            $('#platform').text(platform);


            $.get(url, function (response) {
                        $('#posts_data').html(response);

                    })
                    .done(function () {

                    })
                    .fail(function () {

                    });

        }


    </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

post_ajax.html:
This gets inserted into the title_posts.html at div id="posts_data".

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <article class="media content-section">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.article_title }}</h2>
                        <div class="article-content">{{ post.content|safe }}</div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 post-menu">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" aria-label="Edit">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" aria-label="Delete">
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="row">
            <article class="media content-section">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.article_title }}</h2>
                    <div class="article-content">{{ post.content|safe }}</div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

My post_ajax.html has an if else statement that does not trigger for if user.is_superuser even though I am logged in as superuser. I've tested this on the title_posts.html and it trigger but not on the post_ajax.html

Edit:

views.py

```
class TitlePostAjaxListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'main/posts_ajax.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        title = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return Post.objects.filter(game=title, platform=Platform.objects.filter(
            id=self.kwargs.get('platform_id')).first()).order_by('-date_published')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TitlePostAjaxListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['game'] = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))

        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return HttpResponse(render_to_string(self.template_name, context))
```

Comment: Did you try `{% if request.user.is_superuser %}`, and did you include `django.core.context_processors.request` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py?

Comment: I also tried `{% if request.user.is_superuser %}` and it still does not trigger. `django.core.context_processors.request` is in my settings.py

Comment: Try just putting `{{ user.is_superuser }}` in the template, and let me know what it inputs into the HTML.

Comment: When I put `{{ user.is_superuser }}` in the post_ajax template it returns nothing. But if I use it in the title_posts template it returns `True`

Comment: Does anything happen when `post_ajax.html` is appended to the HTML, or nothing gets added at all?

Comment: The else statement is triggered.

Comment: I see. Add your `title-posts-ajax` view code to your original post, I believe the issue is there.

Comment: on your last line of code, try replacing `return HttpResponse(...)` with `return render(request, self.template_name, context)` and let me know if that works.

Comment: That did it. Thanks man.

Comment: no problem! I added it as an answer so that anyone who has the same problem can find an easy solution. You can press the green “check” mark under it to signify that it resolved your issue. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your last line of code, try replacing `return HttpResponse(...)` with `return render(request, self.template_name, context)` and let me know if that works.

This will add the `request` into the rendering process, allowing you to access `request.user`